# Why my background appears a blue, when I set it transparent?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine

I am trying to render this image with transparent background, but instead it renders as blue. I have checked the world settings, HDRI. The problem only happens in render and not view port. Problem persist in both eevee and cycles. Any help is appreciated.[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're compositing the blue background in. Enter the compositor and either mute the Mix node or remove it.

[image]

Comment: Why does using the Alpha create that thin, blue line? I imagined to be proper about things, the Alpha socket could be filled but its result isn't as clean as omitting the Mix Node. Shouldn't it be pixel perfect?

Comment: @HelloHiHola What thin blue line are you talking about?

Comment: Can't add pictures here but if you drag the Render Layers Alpha into the Composite Alpha socket (looking in Compositor), the results aren't as clean as I would expect. I was curious if you knew why since that seems a formal option of eliminating the blue.

Comment: What you're seeing is the background peeking through the non-100% black of the alpha channel due to antialiasing. Create a Viewer node in the compositor and plug the Alpha into the image input and zoom in to the image - you'll see grey pixels between the white and black. Wherever it's grey, that's where you see some blue peek through. To remove this completely you can put a Luminance Key node with high and low set to 1 between the alpha out of the image and the alpha in of the viewer/composite node.